# Continue countdown timer after pause

Tags: java, android, countdown, countdowntimer, continue

I have a countdown timer, I have a button that pause it, but I need that when you click on button, continue to countdown. I search but couldn't a function related this. How can do it? This is my code, I only managed to restart it, but not continue:

```
private TextView cuentaRegresiva;
private Button btnEmpezar;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean timerHasStarted = false;
private long startTime = 30 * 1000;
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
private long restante;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

btnEmpezar.setOnClickListener(iniciar);

 }

OnClickListener iniciar=new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (!timerHasStarted && !pausado) {
               countDownTimer.start();
               timerHasStarted = true;
               btnEmpezar.setText("Pause");
               pausado=false;
                }
        else if(timerHasStarted && !pausado){
               countDownTimer.cancel();
               timerHasStarted = false;
               btnEmpezar.setText("Restart");
               pausado=true;
              }
        else if(!timerHasStarted && pausado){
            countDownTimer2.start();
            timerHasStarted = true;
            btnEmpezar.setText("Pause");
            pausado=false;
        }
    }
};

public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
      public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
       super(startTime, interval);

      }

      @Override
      public void onFinish() {
          cuentaRegresiva.setText("Tiempo!");
      }

      @Override
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
          cuentaRegresiva.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
      }
     }

public class MyCountDownTimer2 extends CountDownTimer {
          public MyCountDownTimer2(long restante, long interval) {
           super(restante, interval);

          }

          @Override
          public void onFinish() {
              cuentaRegresiva.setText("Tiempo!");
          }

          @Override
          public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
              cuentaRegresiva.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

          }
         }
```

I thought about taking millisUntilFinished to a variable, but didn't work. Anyway I guess the way is close to that.

Comment: The documentation isn't too clear whether you can use _start()_ after _cancel()_ again. I'm guessing it does not work. Though what you could try is store _millisUntilFinished_ value while timer is running. Then once need to re-start the timer, create new timer object and use this value as duration.

Comment: Simple cancel and again start the timer from the last countdown or pass the timer pause state to the timer class and keep check this on timertask and just skip the update. When resume reset the status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try saving the seconds until finish, and then you can start the new countdown timer with that seconds.

// -----------------------

Cuando presionas el boton de pausa, guarda los segundos que le faltan al timer para que termine. Entonces, cuando volves a apretar play, creas un nuevo CountDownTimer con esos segundos que te faltaban.

UPDATE

I did an example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int TIMER_TIME = 10000; // in millis
    private Button btnCountdown;
    private TextView tvTimeUntilFinish;
    private boolean mIsPaused = true;
    private long mMillisUntilFinish;
    private CountDownTimer mTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMillisUntilFinish = TIMER_TIME;

        btnCountdown = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCountdown);
        tvTimeUntilFinish = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeUntilFinish);

        btnCountdown.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (mIsPaused) {
                    btnCountdown.setText("Pause");
                    initTimer();
                } else {
                    btnCountdown.setText("Play");
                    cancelTimer();
                }

                mIsPaused = !mIsPaused;
            }
        });
    }

    private void cancelTimer() {

        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
            mTimer = null;
        }

    }

    private void initTimer() {
        mTimer = new CountDownTimer(mMillisUntilFinish, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tvTimeUntilFinish.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                mMillisUntilFinish = millisUntilFinished;
            }

            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sany. There I edited the code, but I can not get it to work properly. When I reboot It pulled error.
Gracias Sany. Ahí edité el código probando lo que me decis, estoy guardando los segundos restantes en la variable "restante", pero cuando lo reanudo vuelve a tirar error. Por otro lado podrías pasarme tu e-mail o algún contacto ya que tengo muy pocos conocidos programadores que hablen español,  para compartir conocimientos e ideas. Gracias!